# jQuery's trigger() and submit()

Tags: jquery

I have a simple form like this:

```
<form action="">
    <div class="btn">
       <input type="text" name="n" id="form-name">
       <input type="submit" name="go">
    </div>
</form>

<a href="" class="vote" title="test">vote</a>
```

I try to submit it from other buttons (`.vote`):

```
var voteButton = section.find('.vote'),
    storyContainer = $('input[name=n]'),
    storySubmit = $('.btn').find('input[name=go]'),
    storyForm = $('.btn').closest('form');

voteButton.each(function() {
    var title = $(this).attr('data-story');

    $(this).on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('article').animate({opacity: .75},150, function() {
            storyContainer.attr('value', title);
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            storySubmit.trigger('click');

            storyForm.on('submit', function() {
                alert('bam');
                return false;
            });
        },50);

        return false;
    });
});
```

What I want is to submit the form (with `trigger`) but then prevent it from reloading page `with on('submit')`. But it doesn't even go to `submit`, it reloads the page. What can I do?

Comment: Where is your class of "vote"?

Comment: I've added it. Hope it helps!

Comment: What is `section` in `var voteButton = section.find('.vote')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would trigger the form `submit` event using the `.vote` element:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.vote').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prev('form').find(':submit').trigger( 'click' );
    });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
        $('a.vote').on('click',function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).prev('form').find(':submit').trigger( 'click' );
        });
        $('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert( 'The submit event has fired!' );
        });
    });
```

```css
.btn {
  display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="myForm">
    <div class="btn">
       <input type="text" name="n" id="form-name">
       <input type="submit" name="go">
    </div>
</form>

<a href="" class="vote" title="test">vote</a>
```

Comment: I know, but at the moment we're using some kind of weird CMS that has problems with `submit()`. That's why I have to use `trigger`.

Comment: Can you explain a little more on that. Are you saying that event `.trigger( 'submit' )` would not be acceptable?

Comment: Correct, it returns errors within forms. Using `trigger('click')` is the only workaround available.

Comment: Ok, I'll update my answer shortly. One more question, would `.click()` be acceptable?

Comment: I have to hide the submit button, so propably no.

Comment: My answer is updated. The submit button is hidden and I tested both `.trigger('click')`, `.click()` and `[0].click()` and they all work fine.

Comment: Great, but it reloads the page.

Comment: On this code snippet, the page does not reload because form submission is prevented by `e.preventDefault()` in `.on('submit`, ...`. Please ensure that form submission is prevented either by using `<form onsubmit="return false;" ..` or as in the snippet. And remember your data will not hit the server -- think of sending it via ajax.